# How to generate a choropleth map based on region names?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, geospatial, choropleth

I'm working on Python with a dataset that has data about a numerical variable for each italian region, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
regions = ['Trentino Alto Adige', "Valle d'Aosta", 'Veneto', 'Lombardia', 'Emilia-Romagna', 'Toscana', 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia', 'Liguria', 'Piemonte', 'Marche', 'Lazio', 'Umbria', 'Abruzzo', 'Sardegna', 'Puglia', 'Molise', 'Basilicata', 'Calabria', 'Sicilia', 'Campania']
df = pd.DataFrame([regions,[10+(i/2) for i in range(20)]]).transpose()
df.columns = ['region','quantity']
df.head()
```

[image]

I would like to generate a map of Italy in which the colour of the different regions depends on the numeric values of the variable quantity (`df['quantity']`),i.e., a choropleth map like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: I am not sure which map library you would like to use, but in any case, you will need to have the map coordinates ready. As an example, I share an official reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#indexing-by-geojson-properties) with a visualization that combines plolty and geojson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html).

The regions in your df compared to the geojson dont match exactly. I'm sure you can find another one, or alter the names so they match.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

regions = ['Trentino Alto Adige', "Valle d'Aosta", 'Veneto', 'Lombardia', 'Emilia-Romagna', 'Toscana', 'Friuli-Venezia Giulia', 'Liguria', 'Piemonte', 'Marche', 'Lazio', 'Umbria', 'Abruzzo', 'Sardegna', 'Puglia', 'Molise', 'Basilicata', 'Calabria', 'Sicilia', 'Campania']
df = pd.DataFrame([regions,[10+(i/2) for i in range(20)]]).transpose()
df.columns = ['region','quantity']

#Download a geojson of the region geometries
gdf = gpd.read_file(filename=r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')
gdf = gdf.dissolve(by='reg_name') #The geojson is to detailed, dissolve boundaries by reg_name attribute
gdf = gdf.reset_index()

#gdf.reg_name[~gdf.reg_name.isin(regions)] Two regions are missing in your df
#16    Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol
#18    Valle d'Aosta/Vallée d'Aoste

gdf = pd.merge(left=gdf, right=df, how='left', left_on='reg_name', right_on='region')

ax = gdf.plot(
    column="quantity",
    legend=True,
    figsize=(15, 10),
    cmap='OrRd',
    missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'});

ax.set_axis_off();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue with Trentino Alto Adige and Valle d'Aosta is that they are multilingual and I wrote them in the list without mentioning French and German name of the regions. (I had to wrote 'Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol',  'Valle d'Aosta/Vallée' d'Aoste' instead of 'Trentino Alto Adige', "Valle d'Aosta").

Answer (score 0):

If you need a library for geographical analysis within Italy [here](https://github.com/stefanogelli92/geo_ita) you can find mine.

Following how to plot the regional choropleth:

```
plot_choropleth_map_regionale(df, region_tag='column with the region name', value_tag='value to plot')
```